# how to tell axios to exclude cookie in post request

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, http-headers, http-post

I tried to overwrite Cookie and set withCredentials:false, but that didn't work:

```js
const request = await axios({
    url: '/api/payments',
    method: "post",
    data: payload,

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      "Cookie": "access_token=''",
    },

    // auth token as  httponly cookie
    withCredentials: false,
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios is simply a wrapper for the browser's `XMLHttpRequest` functionality, which handles cookies automatically, so there's no way to override that behavior.

As far as the `withCredentials` flag, this would only apply in the context of cross origin requests. Can read more here -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials